# How to make jQuery select exactly the classes specified?

Tags: jquery

html

```
<span class="a">a</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

javascript

```
var obj = $(".a.b"); //selects 2 spans .a .b and .a .b .c
alert($(obj).text());
```

How to make jQuery select the single span with the classes .a and .b only?

I can't use the jQuery not in my case because I might not know about class c ahead of time.

Comment: something like $('.a.b:not(.c)')

Comment: I can't use not because in my case because I might not know about class c ahead of time.

Comment: Edit you question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the other class(es) ahead of time, you can filter out elements that have more than your two target classes:

```js
var obj = $(".a.b").
  filter(
    function() {
      return( this.className.split(/\s+/).length == 2 );
    }
  );

console.log($(obj).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a">a</span>
<span class="a b">a b</span>
<span class="a b c">a b c</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like: `$(":not(selector)")`

Example:
Select all `<p>` elements except those with class="intro":

```
$("p:not(.intro)")
```

In the case you don't want to use `not` method, try this: `$(selector).filter(criteria,function(index))`

Example: Return all `<p>` elements with class name "intro":

```
$("p").filter(".intro")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the jquery `not()` method to take elements out of the results (the oppersite of `add()`). [here are the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

`var results = $('.a').add('.b').not('.c');`

if you only want elements with the class of .a AND .b and no other classes, you'd need to do a reg ex on the `el.className`. checking for any other class name segments in addition to `.a` and `.b`, something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var results = $('.a.b');

    var onlyAAndB = results.filter(function (index, el) {
        var classes = el.className;
        var remaining = classes.replace('a', '').replace('b', '').replace(' ', '');
        if(!remaining) {
            return el;
        }
    });

    console.log(onlyAAndB);
});
```

The above is the longway round and can be shorted with regex rather then replace, im using replace here just to demonstrate the process

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the other answers are a little overkill. You can use [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to specify an exact attribute value like so:

```
$('span[class="a b"]')
```

So long as you're sure the element you want to select will only have those classes this will work.